# IDT done in C is not working

Tags: c, operating-system, interrupt-handling, interrupt, keyboardinterrupt

I am not being able to get IDT working because my Interrupt routines are not getting called, especially the keyboard related one when i press a key on keyboard. I am passing the IDT table's special 48 bit pointer's address. I am doing it like

```
dt_ptr idt_ptr; // defining the pointer
loadidt(dt_ptr *a); // how i am passing the pointer's address to assembly routine
```

I also don't know whether at least GDT is working or not.

1) what shall i do to get my IDT working. I saw few tutorials too but didn't help
2) How can i verify whether GDT works properly?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I am doing this for my own OS. I am doubtful whether my assembly routine is able to properly receive the pointer's address. So i also tried to do lidt using inline assembly but didn't help. I don't know what is wrong. Any clues, idea?

```
void remap_irqs(void)
{
outb(0x20, 0x11);
outb(0xA0, 0x11);
outb(0x21, 0x20);
outb(0xA1, 0x28);
outb(0x21, 0x04);
outb(0xA1, 0x02);
outb(0x21, 0x01);
outb(0xA1, 0x01);
outb(0x21, 0x0);
outb(0xA1, 0x0);
outbyte('a');
```

}

```
void set_idt_gate(uint8 num, unsigned long base, word sel, uint8 flags)
{
IDT[num].offset_low = (base & 0xFFFF);
IDT[num].offset_high = (base >> 16) & 0xFFFF;    
IDT[num].selector = sel;    
IDT[num].zero = 0;
IDT[num].type_attrs = flags;   
}




void init_idt()
{
outbyte('M');   
idt_ptr.limit = (sizeof (idt_entry) * 256) - 1;
idt_ptr.base =(uint32) &IDT;

memset((uint8 *)&IDT, 0, sizeof(idt_entry) * 256);
remap_irqs();
set_idt_gate(0,  (unsigned) irq_0, 0x08, 0x8E);
set_idt_gate(1,  (unsigned) irq_1, 0x08, 0x8E);
//install_isrs();
//install_irqs();   
//idt_load();
//print_message();
lidt(&IDT,idt_ptr.limit);
_LIDT(&idt_ptr);
loadidt(&idt_ptr);
}



void lidt( void * base, unsigned short size )
{
struct
{
    unsigned short length;
    unsigned long base;
} __attribute__((__packed__)) IDTR;

IDTR.length = size;
IDTR.base = (unsigned long)base;
asm( "lidt (%0)"
     : : "p"(&IDTR) );
```

}

```
void _LIDT(dt_ptr *ptr)
{
asm("lidt (%0)" : :"p"(ptr));
outbyte('n');
}





void irq_0()
{
//before_interrupt();
ticks+=1;
if(ticks%18==0)
{
    outbyte('+');
    outbyte('1');
}
//after_interrupt();
}

void irq_1()
{
outbyte('a');
//before_interrupt();
irq1_keyb();
//after_interrupt();
}

typedef struct {
uint16 offset_low;    // The lower 16 bits of the address to jump to when this
interrupt occures:// offset 0-15  
uint16 selector;      // Kernel segment selector in IDT
uint8  zero;          // This must always be zero.
uint8  type_attrs;    //gate types, atttribute types etc.   
uint16 offset_high;   // The upper 16 bits of the address to jump to. offset 16-31 
} __attribute__((__packed__)) idt_entry;  


typedef struct  {
uint16 limit;
uint32 base;      // The address of the first element in IDT array.
} __attribute__((__packed__)) dt_ptr;


global loadidt
loadidt:
push ebp
mov ebp,esp     
mov eax,[ebp+8]     
lidt [eax]    
pop ebp     
ret
```

Comment: For interrupt issues it would be helpful to tell your platform and maybe your operating system.

Comment: My own operating system.

Comment: ...and your platform (i.e., which processor, and in case of interrupt considerations, interrupt controller, if any)

Comment: We need more information. Show us how IDT is created, exact loadidt code and dt_ptr definition.

Answer (score 1):

You set IRQs vector offset to `0x20`. That means `IRQ0` is mapped to interrupt `0x20`, `IRQ1` to interrupt `0x21`, etc. However, you set your irq handlers to be executed when interrupts `0x00` and `0x01` occur. That's how you should set IDR:

```
set_idt_gate(0x20,  (unsigned) irq_0, 0x08, 0x8E);
set_idt_gate(0x21,  (unsigned) irq_1, 0x08, 0x8E);
```

You can find more information regarding PIC [here](http://wiki.osdev.org/PIC) (section *Initialization* explains exactly what you are doing in `remap_irqs` function.

Comment: thank you. Something may be wrong with gdt. as whole no improvement.